# Mean of means by a factor versus global mean

Tags: r, mean

I would pretty much appreciate if someone could explain the discrepancy detailed below.

Let's do a theoretical test first.

```
# make some test data with three levels and a vector of random numbers
test <- data.frame(ind = gl(3, 10), val = runif(30))
# calculate mean by "ind" (stored to a variable for pedagogic purposes
ind.mean <- with(test, tapply(X = val, INDEX = ind, FUN = mean))
# calculating mean of means by "ind" and a global mean yields same results - FINE
mean(ind.mean)
mean(test$val)
```

Here's for some tricky data.

```
rld <- structure(list(date = c("2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009"), pm = c(1, 0.80952380952381, 0.75, 1, 0.866666666666667, 
0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 
0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.714285714285714, 0.833333333333333, 
0.818181818181818, 0.8, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.909090909090909)), .Names = c("date", "pm"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))

> head(rld)
  date        pm
1 2011 1.0000000
2 2011 0.8095238
3 2011 0.7500000
4 2011 1.0000000
5 2011 0.8666667
6 2011 0.8000000
```

One would expect the results to be identical (sensu above test case), alas...

```
> mean(rld$pm)
[1] 0.7822699
> mean(tapply(X = rld$pm, INDEX = rld$date, FUN = mean))
[1] 0.7500214
```

*EDIT*

Chase nailed it. Here's proof:

```
test3 <- data.frame(ind = rep(1:3, times = c(5, 15, 10)), val = runif(30))
> mean(test3$val)
[1] 0.4972464
> mean(tapply(X = test3$val, INDEX = test3$ind, FUN = mean))
[1] 0.468399
```

Comment: This really is a basic math question and not an R question. Perhaps someone with 'power' can redirect the category?

Comment: I was thinking of getting it moved to either math.SE or crossvalidated. Didn't think hard enough before I posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to take the average of a set of averages where each component  made up of a different number of rows:

```
> table(rld$date)
2009 2010 2011 
  11   26    9
```

When you try and take the average of those groups, you assign equal weight to the average from 2009, 2010, and 2011.

I think an easy parallel is thinking about a set of quizzes and tests. Quizzes are more frequent and worth fewer points, so having a 100% average from a set of five quizzes worth 10 points each carries less weight than the midterm which is worth 100 points.

Answer (score 6):

Only when the counts in all groups are the same will the mean of means equal the global mean,

Comment: By "the same" you mean in the same approximate range with a similar distribution?

Comment: No. The same. As in identical.

Comment: I guess I should make explicit that I meant the _counts_ of values, not identical values.